# How can I delete the tmp folder in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I got the fake mail and unfortunately I click wrong link and some file created in the tmp/ folder how can I remove folder in tmp/ ?

Comment: The content of the `/tmp`folder should be removed, when you reboot the computer. If this does not happen, something is very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To delete this folder, you have to do `sudo rm -rf /tmp/<your folder>`

Comment: Warning: Use `rm -rf` with care and generous double-checking. A typo in the wrong place can devastate your system.